# Corrupt JPEG data: 20 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb OpenCV with macOS Mojave

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, face-recognition, macos-mojave

I am developing a simple app in python 3.7, using [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples). Unfortunately a new error started popping up:

```
"Corrupt JPEG data: 20 extraneous bytes before marker 0xdb"
```

The full example which I followed in my code is available [here](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/identify_and_draw_boxes_on_faces.py)

I did research, including:
[this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9477),
[this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2194),
[this](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=8160), and many others. Restarting the system did nothing, nor did reinstallation of `open-cv`, and installation of `opencv-contrib-python`.

As far as I know it's connected to my computer architecture (this seems to only pop up on 64-bit machines), but no one covered that issue for macOS Mojave, and solutions covered in links I attached above don't work for me.

I narrowed it down to the following line, which throws the error. It used to work well, now something changed. No changes were made in code, though. It just started acting out:

```
facial_recognition(face_recognition.load_image_file('img.jpeg'))
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I solved it. It was actually a completely different problem. When you're using pyCharm please remember to close all tabs that are currently running this code in your console. This occurs when you're trying to access the same image file, and modify it at the same time.

Comment: do you have problem to open this JPG in other prorgam ?

Comment: No, I don't. The file itself is fine. What's more when I use openCV to open it - it's fine.